# Diagonal winner checking, tic tac toe

Tags: java, matrix, tic-tac-toe

I have got this method for checking winner in tic tac toe

```
public boolean hasWinner(Cell shape, int row, int col) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i++){
        if(this.board[row][i]==shape){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            count=0;
        }
        if(count>=5){
            return true;
        }
    }
    count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++){
        if(this.board[i][col]==shape){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            count=0;
        }
        if(count>=5){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I've already written code for checking, if there are 5 same symbols consecutively on last added symbol's row and column and now I need to check both diagonals, on which is last added symbol located. Is there any trick, or do I have to write something like `board[row+1][col+1]==shape && board[row+2][col+2]==shape...`?

Comment: I don't understand what your row and column parameters are supposed to do?

Comment: They are coordinates of last added cross or circle

Answer (score 0):

I can't really write you solution now, but I think you are asking about this cycle:

```
        Cell shape = null;
        boolean win = true;

        for(int j=0, k = 0; j < WIDTH) {
            if(shape == null) {
                shape = this.board[j][k];
            } else {
                win = win && this.board[j][k] == shape;
            }

        }
```

which runs through main diagonale, so you don't need write things manually. Then you need do same for second diagonale

But to be honest, if I were you and I had 3 or less rows/columns I would do as you proposed for readablity purposes